# Call method in constructor

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Controller with a constructor where I´m injecting a cache, but also I would like to invoke a method in the constructor when the instance is created. I know we can create some auxiliary constructors with

```
def this(foo:Foo){}
```

But in my case because is play framework the one that instance my bootstrap is a little bit more complex.

Here my code

```
class SteamController @Inject()(cache: CacheApi) extends BaseController {

  private val GAME_IDS_LIST_API: String = "api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2"

  private val GAME_API: String = "store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids="

  private val GAME_KEY: String = "games"

  def games = Action { implicit request =>
    var fromRequest = request.getQueryString("from")
    if (fromRequest.isEmpty) {
      fromRequest = Option("0")
    }
    val from = Integer.parseInt(fromRequest.get) * 10
    val to = from + 10
    loadGameIds()
    Ok(html.games(SteamStore.gamesIds(cache.getVal[JSONArray](GAME_KEY), from, to), cache.jsonArraySize(GAME_KEY)/10))
  }


  private def loadGameIds(): Unit = {
    val games = cache.get(GAME_KEY)
    if (games.isEmpty) {
      get(s"$GAME_IDS_LIST_API", asJsonGamesId)
      cache.set(GAME_KEY, lastResponse.get, 60.minutes)
    }
  }
```

What I would like is that loadGameIds would be invoked and cached when the class is instantiated.

Any suggestion?

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you simply want to add some statements to the main constructor body? If that's the case, you can simply do so in the body of the *class* itself. In your case, that would look like this:

```
class SteamController @Inject()(cache: CacheApi) extends BaseController {

  ...

  private val GAME_KEY: String = "games"

  loadGameIds() // <-- Here we are calling from the main constructor body

  def games = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

When doing so, it is usually a good idea to perform additional code *after* the declaration of all vals and vars in your class, to ensure they are properly initialized at the time your additional constructor code runs.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was trying object init{ loadGameIds } but nothing. That weird that I did not learn that in any blog that I read.